# how to change default browser for wamp?

Tags: php, wamp

recently I installed firefox and now my phpmyadmin will be displayed in firefox but always I used chrome I went to c:\wamp and changed the wampmanager.conf navigator to my chrome strangely it was something about ie explorer and nothing about firefox I updated the line as follow:

```
navigator = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

I restarted the wamp server and no result I read about the wampmaneger.ini but seems that it was for old versions.I don't know what to do?I want my chrome back

Comment: I really don't understand what is preventing you to use the browser you prefer...

Comment: What happens when you open your Chrome browser to `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`?

Comment: I really don't understand either I read alot about it.maybe I should restart the computer?! and not the wamp?:( any ideas?

Comment: @SableFoste it will show me the phpmyadmin! but when I click on the wamp link it will open in firefox

Comment: why votting down? what is wrong with my question?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/226785), what you tried must work... So check if you have done it correctly and try restarting wamp properly (don't restart services, close waamp and start it again or reboot your computer)

Comment: yes I know I used slash and back slash both of them and before this I have read exactly this link that you wrote.I don't know why but the default browser solved the problem after installing firefox it made itself the default and I didn't realized it but I'm still mixed up.

Comment: you got voted down (not by me) because your question is not specificly about programming, there must be someplace else withing stack exchange more fitted for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Chrome your default browser.

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95417

Comment: problem solved.thanks but I really can't understand why when configuring the wamp to use chrome it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I never use the access as you described (I always go to `1127.0.0.1`), but make sure your path to launch the browser is correct.  Checking my own, I see:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`, which is not the same as what you listed above.

Comment: well chrome was installed in the place exactly that I wrote I have windows 64 bit I don't have `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`